# Electric field in QE calculation

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, electric-field

I want to apply an electric field pointing in z-direction to a two-dimensional crystal residing in the xy-plane using Quantum Espresso. So far I noticed that there are two distinct ways to do so either using the input parameters `tefield = .true.` or `lelfield = .true.` in the `&CONTROL` card.

The field should be homogeneous. Is `lelfield = .true.` together with `efield_cart(3)   = 0.01` the correct choice?

Comment: Could you tell us a little bit more about your material such as if it's monolayer or bilayer, and whether the top and bottom layers are equivalent? If that's the case, there will be an artificial electric field already! I am trying to understand if you need a dipole correction or not so that I can write an answer. In general, an external field is simulated by applying a sawtooth potential (due to PBC). In the meantime, you may want to check the following [input parameters](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PW.html#emaxpos): `edir`, `emaxpos`, `eopreg`, `eamp`, `dipfield`

Comment: Also, [this](https://github.com/nguyen-group/QE-SSP/blob/master/bi-gr/elec-field/scf.in) example input file might be helpful. Here, they applied an external electric
field perpendicular to a graphene bi-layer system, i.e., along z-direction. The electric field is not homogeneous though.

Comment: I am actually interested in both, the monolayer and a homo-bilayer (build from two equal monolayers) and how the inversion symmetry breaking of the electric field influences the electronic structure.

Comment: Your comment might not have been seen by @AbdulMuhaymin because you didn't use the @ character to ping him. By the way, I gave my +1 long ago, but have you got an answer from elsewhere over the last few months? Are you still actively in need of an answer to this particular question? Please update us!